# Create/Update list when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox">Item1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox">Item2</label></li>
</ul>
```

I need to track all checkboxes on check/uncheck. If checkbox is checked then I will get the text of the label it belongs to and create another list with it's content

```
var GetChecked = $('label').text();
```

So basically I need to create a new list which will contain all texts from the checkboxes that are Checked. And I need to be able to remove items from that list, if the checkbox which it belongs to is unchecked. And this is the trickiest part for me.

Comment: have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ or write a for loop in pure JS. In the for loop save all the checked items text into an array and then display that array however you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the right direction. I have created a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kumurasqare/t2AKT/6/ But I still can't get how to make sure that only items from submenu are counted and they got properly added/removed when associated checkboxes are checked/uncheckd